# How to detect if instantiated prefab can be placed at current location or not

Tags: unity, c#, collision-detection

I'm using Unity 5.5.0f3 with C#.

My prefab(wooden fence) is instantiated at my mouse location when I click a UI button and follows my mouse until I click somewhere in the scene to place it. The fence has a box collider on it.

Currently, the fence is able to be placed intersecting and even inside of anything else on the scene right now, and I want to eliminate this issue.

I would like my fence (and any other future prefabs) to check if it is intersecting an object's collider when it is following my mouse and turn red if it is, or else be green if it is not to indicate if it can or cannot be placed there and either allow or deny placement accordingly.

I have read that there is no way to do this using transform.position since this is essentially using teleportation on my fence. I tried to use `GetComponent<Rigidbody>().MovePosition(hit.point + positionOffset);` but I get all kinds of weird behavior when I do this.

The following are the three scripts I am using to make this happen:

**Raycast Builder:**

```
public class RaycastBuilder : MonoBehaviour {

    public GameObject defense;
    public Vector3 positionOffset;

    public bool IsPurchased = false;

    public float speed = 2f;

    Vector3 mousePosition;

    BuildManager buildManager;

    void Start ()
    {
        buildManager = BuildManager.instance;
    }

    void Update ()
    {
        GameObject defenseToBuild = buildManager.GetDefenseToBuild();
        if(defenseToBuild == null)
        {
            return;
        }

            //To get the current mouse position
            mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

            Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
            RaycastHit hit;

            if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1 << 8))
            {
            defenseToBuild.transform.position = hit.point + positionOffset;

            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.E))
                {
                    defenseToBuild.transform.Rotate(Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
            if (Input.GetKey(KeyCode.Q))
                {
                    defenseToBuild.transform.Rotate(-Vector3.up * speed * Time.deltaTime);
                }
        }

        if (Input.GetMouseButton(0)&& IsPurchased == true)
        {
            buildManager.SetDefenseToBuild(null);
            IsPurchased = false;
        }

        if(Input.GetKeyDown(KeyCode.Escape))
        {
            buildManager.SetDefenseToBuild(null);
            Destroy(defenseToBuild);
            IsPurchased = false;
        }
    }
}
```

**Shop:**

```
public class Shop : MonoBehaviour {

    BuildManager buildManager;

    void Start ()
    {
        buildManager = BuildManager.instance;
    }

    public void PurchaseWoodenFence ()
    {
        Camera.main.GetComponent<RaycastBuilder>().IsPurchased = true;
        Debug.Log("Wooden Fence Started");
        buildManager.SetDefenseToBuild((GameObject)Instantiate(buildManager.woodenFencePrefab, Vector3.up, Quaternion.identity));
    }

}
```

**Build Manager:**

```
public class BuildManager : MonoBehaviour {

    public static BuildManager instance;

    void Awake ()
    {
        if (instance != null)
        {
            Debug.Log("More than one BuildManager in Scene!");
            return;
        }
        instance = this;
    }

    public GameObject woodenFencePrefab;

    private GameObject defenseToBuild;

    public GameObject GetDefenseToBuild ()
    {
        return defenseToBuild;
    }

    public void SetDefenseToBuild (GameObject defense)
    {
        defenseToBuild = defense;
    }

}
```

Comment: Will your instantiated objects always use a single box collider (simple), or do you need to support arbitrary collision shapes & compounds (substantially more complex)?

Comment: I think just one box collider as far as I can tell, but I am still learning so that very well may change.

Answer (score 1):

I suggest using [isTrigger](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Collider-isTrigger.html) property of collider instead of raycasting.

Basically instantiate the object you want to place in your scene with its isTrigger set to true, and when it is placed (by mouse click), set isTrigger to false to make it work as a normal collider.

Edit: Attaching my code to demonstrate trigger collider. Also, check out the unity documentation entry about [colliders](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/CollidersOverview.html).

```
using UnityEngine;

public class Builder : MonoBehaviour
{
    private int colliderCount = 0;

    private void Update()
    {
        TrackMouse();
        Debug.Log("Number blocking colliders: " + colliderCount);
    }


    private void TrackMouse()
    {
        var mousePosition = Input.mousePosition;

        Ray ray = Camera.main.ScreenPointToRay(mousePosition);
        RaycastHit hit;

        if (Physics.Raycast(ray, out hit, 1 << 8))
            transform.position = new Vector3(hit.point.x, hit.point.y, transform.position.z);
    }

    private void OnTriggerEnter(Collider other)
    {
        colliderCount++;
    }

    private void OnTriggerExit (Collider other)
    {
        colliderCount--;
    }
}
```

Comment: I found references to IsTrigger when I was looking for answers. I tried to use it to see if I could get it to work with a Debug.Log that says "Defense already placed here", but it only printed that to the console when my player ran into it. It didn't say anything when the objects were intersecting while moving them or when they were placed while intersecting. Could you provide a little more insight on what to do with IsTrigger to make it work? perhaps I was using the wrong function when I tried to get it to respond. The fences had rigidbodies on them when I tried this way too.

Comment: Are you sure that you have colliders on both installed and installing object? I will come back if I can make a working example myself.

Comment: Yes they are on both objects, but when the instantiated one is following my mouse, it has no problem going through any other object and being placed inside of them. I was probably making an error on my script for the trigger. I never got it to say anything for the objects intersecting besides when it was with my player. Thank you for taking the time to help me!

Comment: I have edited my answer so you can try the code yourself. You might want to fix the raycasting part to suit your need, since I simplified it for the sake of testing.

Comment: ok, Thank You! I now see the prefabs responding to console when they intersect before placing. I can now use this to tell it its not able to be placed by making a new Boolean and setting it to require true to be placed and having this OnTriggerEnter set the Boolean to false? Does that sound correct?

Comment: Yes. Set the boolean to false OnTriggerEnter, and set it back to true OnTriggerExit.

Comment: Thank You! I have run out of time to test this right now, but I will do it a little later and comment if it worked out for me. Thanks again!

Comment: Alright, So I got it working, sort of. I have one cube I placed in the environment and called TriggerCube. I have it working properly on this cube, but not on any other object. The cube will deny or grant the ability to have objects placed based on the triggers, but every other object that has the script which grants or denies access is not working properly. I also cannot figure out how to turn IsTrigger on or off by using code. Any further help you can think of? been googling again for a little but not luck.

Comment: Okay I tested the situation which you described there, and I think the easiest way to solve it is to track the number of colliders, rather than using a boolean flag. Edited the answer to reflect it, so tell me if you find any other problem with the code.

Comment: You're awesome, Thanks again! I am going out of town early in the morning so I won't get a chance to check the code for a few days. I will let you know how it works though, I am excited to get the issue solved. Thanks!