# Having trouble with foreach loop affecting anything past the first object found

Tags: unity, c#

I have been trying to disable `isTrigger` in unity c# script on all GameObjects containing a certain tag. Currently my code works and disables the isTrigger part of the box collider, but it only does this for the first object with the tag I am looking for do this for all objects.

Here is the code:

```
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine;

public class DefenseCollisionTrigger : MonoBehaviour {

    public static Rigidbody rb;
    public bool CanBePlaced;
    public GameObject[] defenseTriggers;

    void Start ()
    {
        CanBePlaced = true;
        defenseTriggers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Defense");
    }

    public void OnTriggerEnter (Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Defense")
        {
            CanBePlaced = false;
        } 
    }

    public void OnTriggerExit(Collider other)
    {
        if (other.tag == "Defense")
        {
            CanBePlaced = true;
        }
    }

    public void IsTriggerFalse()
    {
        foreach (Object dt in defenseTriggers)
        {
            Debug.Log("working on it");
            GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = false;
        }
    }
}
```

That is what is currently looks like. The `public void IsTriggerFalse()` is called on each time I go to instantiate an object with my mouse button. The Debug.Log is working and printing to the console. This is the closest I have came to making it work, but it only works for the first object. I have searched for hours and watched videos/looked at unity docs on foreach statements with no luck to my issue. I have also tried `using foreach (GameObject dt in defenseTriggers)` instead of just Object.

Anyone know how to solve my issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well, I found the Answer. Not sure how good this is for performance or if it is advised against, but it is working for me!

I had to put the line

```
defenseTriggers = GameObject.FindGameObjectsWithTag("Defense");
```

into my IsTriggerFalse(); area so that it checks for the objects that were being instantiated. Thank you Byte56 for showing me that they weren't being recognized since they were not there at the time of the Start() call.

Answer (score 1):

It's actually only working on the Object that's calling the code.

```
foreach (Object dt in defenseTriggers)
{
    Debug.Log("working on it");
    GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = false;
}
```

Is the same as:

```
foreach (Object dt in defenseTriggers)
{
    Debug.Log("working on it");
    this.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = false;
}
```

Notice the `this.`. Meaning, for each object, you're getting the collider on the **current object** and setting it's `isTrigger` to false.

What you really want is something like this:

```
foreach (GameObject dt in defenseTriggers)
{
    Debug.Log("working on it");
    dt.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = false;
}
```

Comment: It still works the same with any of that code being used. I have a basic scene with one cube in it, a floor, and my player. The cube is the only thing that has the isTrigger get disabled by this code. I am instantiating objects that follow my mouse, and then when I click it places them and then calls this IsTriggerFalse() code that we are looking at. It is all working except for the instantiated objects never get their trigger set to false. They have this script on the prefab as well and in scene when they are instantiated. I tried all the code changes you provided, but no luck yet.

Comment: And "working on it" gets printed to the log the correct number of times? What other debugging steps have you taken? How many times is this script in the scene? You've checked the tags on your objects? Do those objects exist when the `Start()` method is being called?

Comment: Yes it gets printed every time it should be. It is currently only two different objects I am working with. One is a Cube called TriggerCube and the other is a instantiated prefab called WoodenFence(Clone). The fence one gets put on there multiple times correlating to how many fences I have placed in the scene, but none of the fence isTrigger ever get set to false. This script is only on my Empty GameObject that handles stuff in the background of the scene, a cube, and my instantited prefabs. the prefabs are not in the scene at the time of the Start (), but they do have this script attached.

Comment: I have done minimal debugging. just that Debug.Log I posted. I am pretty new to unity so I am still trying to learn so much at the moment. The tags are the same on the objects. The cube that this code is working on has the same tag as the fences that the code is not working on.

Comment: If the objects aren't in the scene when the object holding this script calls `Start()` then the objects aren't going to be added to the list `defenseTriggers`. Attach the debugger and set a break point on the `foreach (GameObject dt in defenseTriggers)` line. See what's inside of `defenseTriggers`, where it's being called from and how many times it's being called.

Comment: The objects have the script attached to them, wouldn't that make the start function call again when they are instantiated? can you tell me a way to disable the isTrigger function on the new objects? I have been trying to figure it out for days and this is as close as I got :/ . I need them to be a trigger when placing them so that they cannot intersect other things with colliders, but I need them to not be a trigger after I place them so that you cannot walk through them. Just seen your edit, how do I attach that debugger with a break point? sorry, im not familiar with it.

Comment: Why not just disable the collider on the object being placed, so it can't interact with existing/already placed objects? It sounds like you need some kind of GameManager with static methods for acting on all the objects so far. You shouldn't have each object trying to track all the other objects, it should be happening in one place only. Otherwise you get a mess like this.

Comment: This is just what I was suggested to do on my last question I asked here https://gamedev.stackexchange.com/questions/146450/how-to-detect-if-instantiated-prefab-can-be-placed-at-current-location-or-not . I am not sure how I would stop the objects from being placed inside each other. I currently have some OnTriggerEnter and Exits in place that stop them from being able to be placed inside of each other by the user. This works on the cube, but since I cannot currently figure out how to disable isTrigger on my fences, it does not work on them. I need the collider to be on them/active when placed

Answer (score 0):

Well I think you forgot to reference the ***dt*** Object in core operation.

```
public void IsTriggerFalse() {
    foreach (Object dt in defenseTriggers) {
        Debug.Log("working on it");
        dt.GetComponent<Collider>().isTrigger = false;
    }
}
```